# Why MATLAB warn me about nonexistent path?

Tags: matlab, path, warnings

I'm using MATLAB 2015a. few days ago I added a toolbox to my path called `SPAMS` and for some reason I deleted the toolbox.

When I went to MATLAB `set path` to remove its address, the address was not there!

Now, every time I start MATLAB, it warns me about a nonexistent address of that toolbox and still it is not in the path: `Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory`

I'm quite sure that address is not in the MATLAB path and neither `startup.m` nor any other file adds it to dynamic path.

What are these warnings for?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: If it wasn't in your path or path definition then you wouldn't get the warning. What does `which pathdef` return?

Comment: @excaza it returned my `pathdef.m` file and I could find `spams` inside this file. Thanks. post it as a response please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because those non-existing path are still saved. Matlab does not list them since the path do not exist. You can simply "Save" the path once after you start Matlab, so update the saved path, and avoid warning in the future sessions.